# Skipping sections in numbering

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I'd like to note include some numberings in sections in my document. For example, by simply doing

```
\section{}

\section{}

\section{}
```

I'll get a 1, 2, and a 3. But what if I wanted it to be labeled 1, 2, and 10? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{}

\section{}

\addtocounter{section}{7}
\section{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: alternatively, `\setcounter{section}{10}` if the section number is to remain at 10 even if another section is added in between.